# xampp website fails to launch

Tags: xampp, localhost, mamp

I have a bunch of my website based projects that work perfectly fine on my xampp localhost. However, with the same settings i fail to launch one of my projects for some reason. It just keeps establishing a connection and tries connecting forever. I have everything set up, but I don;t seem to understand whats wrong. I donot know what additional information to provide, but would be great if you could let me know if anyone had similar issues to this before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check the index file for the project and also the location of the project, full path or relative path.